# java.lang.NullPointerException over a SVGPath LinkedList

Tags: java, svg, linked-list, javafx-2

i create a SVGPath LinkedList however, when i iterate over this list i'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It's a simple LinkedList which has a size of 9. here you can see the code below.

```
public class RiskControllerClass implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_1; // Alaska

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_2; // NorthWest_Ter

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_3; // Greenland

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_4; // Quebec

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_5; // Ontario

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_6; // Alberta

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_7; // E_America

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_8; // W_America

    @FXML
    private SVGPath NA_9; // C_America

    private LinkedList<SVGPath> regions = new LinkedList<>();

    private String nodeID;

    public RiskControllerClass() {

        regions.add(NA_1);
        regions.add(NA_2);
        regions.add(NA_3);
        regions.add(NA_4);
        regions.add(NA_5);
        regions.add(NA_6);
        regions.add(NA_7);
        regions.add(NA_8);
        regions.add(NA_9);

        System.out.println("Length : " + regions.size());

                for (Iterator<SVGPath> iter = regions.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    SVGPath sVGPath = iter.next();

                    System.out.println(sVGPath.getId());
                }

    }
```

when i try to print just only sVGPath like `System.out.print(sVGPath)` it prints all the values `null`. however, when i print the size of list it gives 9 !. how it could be ?. i will appreciate if you can help and thanks anyway.

Comment: It is easy - you've added 9 nulls. From point of view of Java, everything is ok.

Comment: Seems, you start to add NA_i before fields were initialised.

Comment: Correct time of those fields initialisation need to be investigated according to documention (I don't know =) )

Comment: well these fields actually initialized in a .fxml file not in a main class or something. but i guess i should search about this :D

Comment: the fact, that fields are null is clear. The more interesting thing here - when they become not null. FXML loader will fill them when will load the scenegraph, and at some moment they will be initialised. The good point here - is to investigate, when does it happen. And leave it as an answer. (possibly, reformulate the question, about the time of fields init). About the pattern of their usage.

Comment: they are initialized in .fxml file so in my opinion i should create a collection in this file and add the elements in this section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: A `java.util.LinkedList` can contain `null` entries.

Detailed answer: Your code is in the constructor of the class, so it's virtually impossible that some framework (FXML) could have put values into `NA_1`, `NA_2`, ..., `NA_9`. So you are now adding nine uninitialized fields to your `LinkedList`. Uninitialized fields in Java are always `null`. So your list contains 9 elements, all of which are `null`.